# Multiphase levelset Chan Vese algorithm

Tags: image-processing

I am implementing the multiphase level Chan Vese algorithm. I am using IPOL document as reference (http://www.ipol.im/pub/art/2012/g-cv/article.pdf)

Everything is clear for me, except the stopping criteria: 
In one level set, the method is terminated by calculating the difference between phi(n+1) and phi(n), and stop if below some threshold. My problem is how to represent this stopping condition when I have phi1 and phi2?
Also, how I represent the new segmented image? In one level set, I used phi and manipulate it to zero or one values. But, now how I should represent the new segmented image?

Thank you

Comment: This is probably better for comp sci or MATLAB forum , but +1 for interesting